# Close socket if there is a period of inactivity in a multi-connection webserver

Tags: c, sockets, http-1.1

I am building a webserver which can accept and handle multiple client connections. I'm using `select()` for this.
Now while this is going on, if a particular connected socket hasn't had any activity (send or recv) on it, I want to close it. So if no requests come from a connected client for a period of time, I'll close the socket. There are multiple such connected sockets and I need to do this monitoring for each.

I need this functionality to create persistent connections as my webserver has to support HTTP 1.1

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest setting the timeout of the call to `select` to be the minimum time until the next socket will timeout.  Then, if it timed out, close the idle sockets, and repeat.  Something like this pseudocode:

```
timeout = default_timeout;
foreach(socket s)
{
    timeout = min(timeout, (s.last_send_or_recv_time + IDLE_TIMEOUT - now()));
}

result = select(..., timeout);
if(result == 0)
{
    foreach(socket s)
    {
        if(now() - s.last_send_or_recv_time >= IDLE_TIMEOUT)
        {
            close(s);
            remove_from_socket_list(s);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // Handle received data, update last_send_or_recv_time, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using threads and blocking mode, you just need to set a suitable SO_RCVTIMEOUT on the socket and when you get `read()` returning -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`, the timeout has happened, so you just close the socket and exit the thread.

If you're using `select()` it's more complicated. Adam Rosenfield's suggestion looks plausible on the surface, but in practice, if the other sockets are busy enough, the `select()` timeout might never happen at all, or at least not happen for many minutes after a socket actually became too dead. If you want to enforce the timeout strictly, as you should in a server, you have to associate a last-read time with each socket and, at the bottom of the `select()` loop, iterate over the `fd` set picking out those fds that were *not* ready, check their last-read time, and close the ones that are too dead.